# (vscode) Changing one of the fonts that the Tomorrow Night theme uses?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Right now, the theme is using #CC6666 which is a red color and I would like it to use #FFFFFF which is white.  The link to their github where I found the font color is here: (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-themes/blob/master/tomorrow/themes/Tomorrow_Night.tmTheme)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - just find the file that you downloaded (Tomorrow_Night for me) in the ".vscode/extensions" folder and just edited the #CC6666 to #FFFFFF and saved to overide the theme.